Razorpay Subscription manual payment initiate after pending status
if the recurring payment is failed and status moved to  pending ) if i try to pay using their short url i can pay. but i am not able show payment screen with that subscription id to get payment from user.
if the recurrent payment is failed for any reason i want show renew button to make payment. but iam not able to open that payment  screen it shows the follwing error. i am only passing the subscription id to make payment. as i did it after creating subscription (it worked at that time)
{
"error": {
    "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
    "description": "Invalid request payload",
    "step": "NA",
    "reason": "NA",
    "source": "NA"
}

}
